# Press save button in file download dialog from code

Tags: vb.net

I have a WebBrowser control that is automatically logging me into a website and attempting to download ZIP file automatically. Everything is working fine, except, when it tries to download the ZIP, it is popping up a dialog box, asking if I want to save the file or open it (just like in IE). What I am trying to do is automatically download the ZIP file to a file of my choosing . I can't seem to figure out how to suppress the dialog box and capture the download automatically. when i try to download by using WebClient it saves the html page not the zip.

I need to press the save botton in file download popup. Here I am not able to use sendKey.

Please help me...
thanks

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Try      
        If (Label6.Text <> "Got Url") Then  
            If WebBrowser1.Document.Title = "Login" Then
                If ls_IsloginDone Then Exit Sub                    
                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user").SetAttribute("value", "user")
                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pwd").SetAttribute("value", "pwd")
                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnLogin").InvokeMember("click")                    
                ls_IsloginDone = True
            End If
            If WebBrowser1.Document.Title = "Home" Then
                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("menuBar_productLink").InvokeMember("click")
            ElseIf WebBrowser1.Document.Title.Contains("Downloads") Then                    
                Dim ls_ulr1 As String = String.Empty
                If Not IsNothing(WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("repDownloads__ctl1_hypVer")) Then
                    Dim lsohtml As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("repDownloads__ctl1_hypVer").OuterHtml
                    If lsohtml.Contains("downloadURL") Then
                        Dim lsindex As String = lsohtml.IndexOf(""">")
                        Try
                            ls_ulr1 = lsohtml.Substring(lsohtml.IndexOf("downloadURL=") + 13, Math.Abs(lsindex - lsohtml.IndexOf("downloadURL=")) - 13)
                        Catch ex As Exception

                        End Try
                    End If                    
                End If
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ls_ulr1) Then                        
                    Label6.Text = "Got Url"                        
                    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://some.website.com/" & ls_ulr1)
                End If                   
            End If
        ElseIf (Label6.Text = "Got Url") Then
            If Not IsNothing(WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hypDownload")) Then
                Label6.Text = "Url fired"
                Dim href As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hypDownload").GetAttribute("href")                    
                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hypDownload").InvokeMember("click")                    
            End If
        ElseIf isDwldComplete = True Then
            Label6.Text = "Download completed"
            MessageBox.Show("Download complete")
        End If            
    Catch ex As Exception
        ls_err += " " & ex.ToString & vbNewLine
    End Try
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ls_err) Then
        TextBox2.Text = ls_err
        TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you are using to do this?